# Finding new position of 350 randomly positioned discs on 2D plane with avoiding overlapping in mind

Tags: python, 2d

I have roughly about 350 discs (circles with same, constant radius). I use Pillow (python's image manipulation lib) as visualisation library, but this is not that important. All (300-400) discs are placed on 2D plane randomly. So some of them are overlapping. I need to move overlapping discs to new positions (it can be made in many steps!) until all discs are on plane separated (they could have contact, but not overlap). The 2D plane have some constraints (mxn pixels size). I hope you understand how the problem looks like. I want to do it in Python, as I am familiar with this language.

**Are there any algorithms that solve such problem?**

The only comes to my mind is "brute force": move randomly discs (random distance and direction) until all are in correct (not overlapping) positions. But this is not the nicest solution of the problem and rather time- and resource-consuming. I think this not the good idea.

I would like to go different path, that's why I am asking if there is some algorithm to this problem? Can't find anything similar in SO.

I am not asking for code or solution, just for advice.

Comment: Do you have any constraints, or definitions of what a "good" solution would be, or the discs can be placed in any manner as long as they don't overlap?

Comment: Completely in any manner, just not overlapping (they can contact - "one pixel overlapping" - I mean distance_from_centers = 2*R ). The second conditon all must be inside m by n pixels box. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the simplest solution would be to put as many discs as they fit in a row, then start another row and so on. So for `r=5` the centers would be at coords `(5,5)`, `(5,15)`, ..., `(5,x*5)`, `(15,5)`, `(15,15)`, ..., `(15,x*5)`, ..., `(y*5,5)`, `(y*5,15)`, ..., `(y*5,x*5)`, where `x` and `y` are the numbers of columns and rows you will use.

You may probably save some space by intertwining the discs like this:

[image]

The centers will be at `(5,5)`, `(5+d,5+d)`, `(5,5+2d)`, ..., where `d` is an offset computed using the Pythagorean theorem: `d = math.ceil(sqrt((r*2)**2/2))` (we need to round the result up)

Comment: Quite nice idea. I will take it into consideration. Thanks.